iPhone connected to hotspot on another device, does it treat it as wifi or data?
I found similar questions but none of them answers whether the connected device treats the hotspot as wifi or data. Meaning that when one can, say, limit app updates to wifi only, does it apply to hotspot connection as well? It would make sense because often one wants to be efficient with the hotspot data as well.

What is the connected device?  A Mac or an iDevice?

It's an iPhone connected to Galaxy S23.

As far as the phone is concerned, it's WiFi. It doesn't know how the other end is connected to the Internet, whether it's an ISP or cellular data.

If the other end is also iPhone it would likely know how it connects to internet (through apple proprietary protocols) and automatically set low data mode accordingly. Otherwise you would have to manually do that yourself.
